# Search first N sorted integers from an unsorted array length M?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Failed an interview on an algorithm question about how to search first N minimum/maximum ordered integers from an unsorted integer array size M days ago.

From my perspective, all search problems can be converted to be solved by a binary search tree data structure which has the log2N time complexity or its extension such as B+ tree.

For this problem, I build a binary search tree at first and then do a search N count afterwards.
Therefore, the complexity is should be

- Consumed in building tree : M * Log2 M  +
- Consumed in searching the tree : N * Log2 M
- Total : = (M + N) log2 M

I can't find a better solution, so I post my code here and sincerely hope you guys have a better one.
The code is very casual but works. It is only for point out my idea.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SearchFirstNFromM
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] m = new int[10000];   //INPUT M - int array
            int n = 10;                 //INPUT N - int

            Console.WriteLine("Integer Array");
            Random rd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < m.Length; i++)
            {
                m[i] = rd.Next(0, m.Length);
                Console.Write(m[i] + " ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Node root = BuildBinarySearchTree(m); //Building binary search tree
            Console.WriteLine("First N in ordered tree");
            Console.Write("Expected Result : ");
            m.OrderBy(t => t).Take(N_Counter).ToList().ForEach(t => Console.Write(t + " "));
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Actual Result : ");
            DisplayFirstN(root);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            N_Counter = n; //Counter Reset
            Console.WriteLine("Last N in ordered tree");
            Console.Write("Expected Result : ");
            m.OrderByDescending(t => t).Take(N_Counter).ToList().ForEach(t => Console.Write(t + " "));
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Actual Result : ");
            DisplayLastN(root);
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static int N_Counter = 10;

        static void DisplayFirstN(Node root)
        {
            if (root != null)
            {
                if (root.Left != null)
                    DisplayFirstN(root.Left);

                if (N_Counter-- > 0)
                    Console.Write(root.Data + " ");

                if (root.Right != null)
                    DisplayFirstN(root.Right);
            }
        }

        static void DisplayLastN(Node root)
        {
            if (root != null)
            {
                if (root.Right != null)
                    DisplayLastN(root.Right);

                if (N_Counter-- > 0)
                    Console.Write(root.Data + " ");

                if (root.Left != null)
                    DisplayLastN(root.Left);
            }
        }

        static void DisplayTree(Node current)
        {
            if (current != null)
            {
                if (current.Left != null)
                    DisplayTree(current.Left);

                Console.Write(current.Data + " ");

                if (current.Right != null)
                    DisplayTree(current.Right);
            }
        }

        static Node BuildBinarySearchTree(int[] m)
        {
            Node root = new Node(m[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < m.Length; i++)
            {
                Node current = root;
                while (true)
                {
                    if (m[i] >= current.Data)
                    {
                        if (current.Right == null)
                        {
                            var newNode = new Node(m[i]);
                            newNode.Parent = current;
                            current.Right = newNode;
                            break;
                        }

                        current = current.Right;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (current.Left == null)
                        {
                            var newNode = new Node(m[i]);
                            newNode.Parent = current;
                            current.Left = newNode;
                            break;
                        }

                        current = current.Left;
                    }
                }
            }
            return root;
        }

        class Node
        {
            public Node(int data)
            {
                this.Data = data;
            }

            public Node Parent { get; set; }
            public Node Left { get; set; }
            public Node Right { get; set; }
            public int Data { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: This [e-book](http://www.mktechnicalclasses.com/Notes/Cracking%20the%20Coding%20Interview,%204%20Edition%20-%20150%20Programming%20Interview%20Questions%20and%20Solutions.pdf) provides answers, check it out.

Comment: There is a QuickSelect method that might be much faster,  Quick select i based on the QuickSort  algorithm.  The QuickSelect makes a shortcut when it has found the N lowest values.  Note that the lowest values are not in order.

Comment: It might be that I have completely missed what is asked here, but as I understood it with my lackluster english, couldn't you just do a quicksort and choose the first/last N integers? Or are the integers already sorted in the otherwise unsorted array? In that case there is a simple O(M) solution

Comment: Hi @Olavi Mustanoja, You are probably right. I am looking into an algorithm - Quick Select , which is mentioned by Casperah and is very familiar with how QuickSort works. This might be the correct

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Quickselect_algorithm#C.23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those viewers who don't know why they've got here.

There is a useful link with a perfect solution solving problems in this scenario and it is described by a wide range of programming languages.

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Quickselect_algorithm

By the way, inspired by that algorithm , I create a new select algorithm.
Welcome for any comments!

```
 public class myQuickSelect
    {
        public static int[] TakeSmallestNthNumbers(int[] array, int n)
        {
            int startIndex = 0;
            int endIndex = array.Length - 1;
            int remainingCount = n;

            array = (int[])array.Clone();

            Random rd = new Random();
            while (startIndex < endIndex)
            {
                //Randomly pick a number in searching section
                int pivotIndex = rd.Next(startIndex, endIndex);

                pivotIndex = Partition(array, startIndex, endIndex, pivotIndex);

                int foundCount = pivotIndex - startIndex + 1;

                if (foundCount == remainingCount)
                    break;

                if (foundCount > remainingCount)
                {
                    endIndex = --pivotIndex;
                }
                else
                {
                    remainingCount -= foundCount;
                    startIndex = ++pivotIndex;
                }
            }

            return array.Take(n).ToArray();
        }

        private static int Partition(int[] array, int startIndex, int endIndex, int pivotIndex)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Pivot Index:" + pivotIndex);

            Swap(array, startIndex, pivotIndex);
            int pivot = array[startIndex];
            while (startIndex < endIndex)
            {
                while (startIndex < endIndex && array[endIndex] >= pivot) endIndex--;
                array[startIndex] = array[endIndex];
                while (startIndex < endIndex && array[startIndex] < pivot) startIndex++;
                array[endIndex] = array[startIndex];
            }
            array[startIndex] = pivot;
            return startIndex;
        }

        private static void Swap(int[] array, int index1, int index2)
        {
            if (index1 == index2)
                return;

            int t = array[index1];
            array[index1] = array[index2];
            array[index2] = t;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good answer. The time complexity of Quickselect is O(n), where `n` is the number of items in the array. You should note that with a given array, Quickselect takes the same amount of time to select 1% of the items as it does to select 90% of the items. Also, Quickselect doesn't *sort* the selected items. To get a sorted list of k items, then, requires O(n) + O(k log k). Empirical results show that using Heap select is faster than Quickselect when you're choosing a small percentage (approximately 1%) of the items. See http://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/ for more info.

Comment: You might also be interested in [Creating a TopBy method for LINQ to Objects](http://blog.mischel.com/2014/02/13/creating-a-topby-method-for-linq-to-objects/)

Answer (score 2):

A better and relatively simple way to solve this is to use [a heap data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)).
The algorithm then would be:

For the first N elements, insert into heap (O[log N]).
For each of the remaining M-N elements, compare it to the minimum value in the heap (O[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure))).
If it is greater, delete the smallest heap value and insert it into the heap (O[log N]).
Lastly, generate a sorted list from the heap (O[N log N]).

Total complexity: M log N + N log N.  If M is much bigger than N, this is a win over an M log M sort.

Comment: Good answer. Also note that if M is much larger than N, using a heap is a win over Quickselect.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no performance requirement the simplest way would be:

```
using System.Linq;
...
var rnd = new Random();
var m = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).Select(i => rnd.Next(10000));
var result = m.OrderBy(i => i).Take(n);
```

Your code is good, however it might be overly complicated for the simple answer that the interviewer was expecting.  Next time try to ask if he/she wants a simple/strait forward solution to the problem.

Good luck, you have a potential far be on the requirements of that company.

Comment: Oh, yes, I should try to debug into .net framework original source code to see how the Microsoft guys do the same thing. Thanks for inspiration.

Comment: Sorry, if I offended you, it was unintentional, you should be proud, you have created a working solution.  However, you should always choose the simplest solution first.  Only if performance is an issue you should go for the optimized algorithms.

Comment: @Casperah It is an interview question. Perhaps they were looking for an out of the box answer (simplest) but I guess not. In general of course your answer is the best untill you have proof you have performance issues